# Set tab close button position on vertical tabs issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to change the default tab widget close button and set my icon instead. The problem is that it draws the icon on the text. I want to draw the X to the right.

**Code:**

```
void AppTabBar::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QStylePainter painter(this);
    QStyleOptionTab opt;

    for (int i = 0; i < this->count(); i++) {
        initStyleOption(&opt, i);
        opt.text = painter.fontMetrics().elidedText(opt.text, Qt::ElideRight, 70);
        painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_TabBarTabShape, opt);
        painter.save();
        QSize s = opt.rect.size();

        if (tabPos != AppTabPosition::Top && tabPos != AppTabPosition::Bottom) {
            s.transpose();
        }

        QRect r(QPoint(), s);
        r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center());
        opt.rect = r;

        QPoint c = tabRect(i).center();
        painter.translate(c);

        if (tabPos == AppTabPosition::Left) {
            painter.rotate(90);
        } else if (tabPos == AppTabPosition::Right) {
            painter.rotate(270); //90 - left pos, 270 - right pos
        }

        painter.translate(-c);
        painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt);
        painter.restore();
    }

    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}


void AppTabStyle::drawPrimitive(QStyle::PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
{
    if (element == PE_IndicatorTabClose) {
        int size = proxy()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_SmallIconSize);
        QIcon::Mode mode = option->state & State_Enabled ? (option->state & State_Raised ? QIcon::Active : QIcon::Normal) : QIcon::Disabled;

        if (!(option->state & State_Raised) && !(option->state & State_Sunken) && !(option->state & QStyle::State_Selected)) {
            mode = QIcon::Disabled;
        }

        QIcon::State state = option->state & State_Sunken ? QIcon::On : QIcon::Off;
        QPixmap pixmap = QIcon(":/Icons/cross_icon.png").pixmap(size, mode, state);
        proxy()->drawItemPixmap(painter, option->rect, Qt::AlignRight, pixmap);
    } else {
        QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget);
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image: 2021-05-13_200839.png]

This issue only appears on the vertical tabs (`AppTabPosition::Left` or `AppTabPosition::Right`). Any ideas how to draw it to the right?

**Edited (15.05.2021):**
I have set `setTabsClosable(false);`, then created the `TabBarLabel` class and set it to `setTabButton` method. It closes the tabs but the issue with overlapping the tab text still exists:

**Screenshot:**
[image: vertical_tabs_issue_example.gif]

It is a lot of code, so I have created and uploaded to `Mega` the test example to illustrate this issue. Here is my test example: [TabExample.zip](https://mega.nz/file/hY4yVBgA#8HK7luiFigx0DO1IKcjey_6HBD7DgFDPQST9GUEz9p4) (6kb)

Any ideas how to change position of tab bar close button? Thank you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! I have fixed the issue with vertical tab close button position.

**Code:**

```
if (tabPos != AppTabPosition::Top && tabPos != AppTabPosition::Bottom) {
    s.transpose();

    if (this->tabsClosable()) { // check if tab is closable
        QRect optRect = opt.rect;
        optRect.setX(90); // set X pos of close button
        optRect.setY(optRect.y() + 8); // calcs the Y pos of close button
        optRect.setSize(QSize(12, 12));
        this->tabButton(i, QTabBar::RightSide)->setGeometry(optRect);
   }
}
```

Here I do not change the default `opt.rect` but instead I copy it to new `QRect`. Then I change the size and position of `optRect`  and finally set geometry to `tabButtton` .

**Screenshot:**

[image]

The issue is resolved.